# Resize disk size of vm in VirtualBox not working

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox. My old disk size was 25 GB, and I want to change it to 50 GB.

I resize my disk size by:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd Win7_64bit.vdi --resize 50000
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

I can see the disk size has been successfully changed in VM details panel:
[image]

But when I try to extend disk in my VM, there is no unallocated space in it:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: As you can see in your screenshots the VM doesn't use `disk.vdi` but rather `Win7_64bit.vdi`.

Comment: @Seth My bad. I was actually using Win7_64bit.vdi in my command. Fixed in question.

Comment: use some 3rd party tools like [partition wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/), [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/) or [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html) to resize. Windows disk management is very bad at partitioning and doesn't have ability to expand a partition

Comment: Do you have any snapshots on the VM that might be interfering? Is it a linked VM? @LưuVĩnhPhúc it actually is capable of doing so and it's even able to shrink partitions.

Comment: @Seth I do have a snapshot. It was created right after I installed my VM. Is that the reason? It's not a linked VM. It was newly installed by wizard.

Comment: It might be. Right now I'm not sure how VirtualBox snapshots work. Depending on it the snapshot itself could contain the information about the device size. You could try to make a full copy of the VM, remove the snapshot and have a look whenever you're seeing the full disk size afterwards.

Comment: @Seth yes diskmgmt.msc can shrink the partition, although with very limited capability compared to 3rd party ones, but it has no expand capability, except on dynamic disks. If you right click on it you'll see the expand option, but that's greyed out because it's only for dynamic disks

Comment: I don't know where you got that information but it's been wrong at least [since Windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473(v=ws.11).aspx). It's perfectly possible to expand basic disks. In fact shrinking is usually a much more complex process than extending. In addition the OP has a problem on a much higher level. The VM doesn't see the increased disk size. So even if you use another utility it wouldn't be able to extend the disk. There is no physical space available within the VM for the extend.

Comment: @MartinZhai Did you ever figure this out? I just went through the same thing and notice that the unallocated space is not showing.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ No.. I just gave up after tried so many times.

Comment: @MartinZhai Thanks, yeah I came to the same conclusion myself, already moved on and made another one. It was less aggravation.